# How to create JqueryUI like own UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am working with JqueryUI from some months, I want to know can we change the theme of components.

Comment: Create your own library, theme, plugins, what exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are asking for good looking GUI components. you can use following components, for which you can change theme.

- **ThemeRoller**

  jQuery UI is a curated set of user interface interactions, effects, widgets, and themes built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library.
- **Apache Pivot**

  Apache Pivot™ is an open-source platform for building installable Internet applications (IIAs).
- **JavaFX UI Controls**

  The JavaFX UI controls are built by using nodes in the scene graph. Therefore, the controls can use the visually rich features of the JavaFX platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean changing the theme, colors etc. you can use jQuery's Themeroller:

[ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, whether you're asking for custom or creating your own library(this will consume a lot of time).

Yes possible using [**ThemeRoller**](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), where you can create your own custom designs.

1. Customize the designs
2. Get the library generated and add it to your work.